# Windows japanese keeps turning to kana when i am on hirigana

Tags: windows-10, japanese

I have been using the japanese downloadable keyboard on windows 10, with the ime program (or whatever its called) however, recently every time i put in a "n" it turns it into kana instead of the hirigana, witch is selected. ン　
I dont know what is causing this, and it does it automaticallly every time i type a "n" and a space. I have tried resetting all the settings, but it doesnt change anything, I have also tried to reset all of the settings i possibly could in the advanced menu, but it still changes my "n"s into kana instead of hirigana, like it does with all the other romaji i type. someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

Case 1) You have accidentally pressed *ひらがな/カタカナ* key on your keyboard

Case 2) You have accidentally pressed *無変換* key on your keyboard, you can press that again then it turns "Hiragana" > "Katakana" "Half width Katakana" > "Hiragana" and repeat this.

Case 3) System overrides the input mode.

First press this button:

[image]

Select 'general' tab,

1. on the first column 'Input method' choose "Romaji"
2. on the second column, 'Initial inpud mode' choose "Hiragana"
3. Press OK